# Sticky :hover styling when closing accordion panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I have a simple accordion that when you open a panel a class of `.open` is added to the title + content group so I can style it. This works fine but I've noticed on my phone that when I click to close a panel my hover styling (which is the same as the active/open styling) remains. As I use a plus/minus icon, this causes it all to go out of sync. Clicking elsewhere on the page removes the styling though. There is no `:focus` styling so it must be the `:hover` being interpreted as a touch event? Can anyone suggest how I can prevent this?

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Add class of `.open` to first `.accordion__title` as it is set to `display: block` in CSS.
    $('.accordion__item:first-child .accordion__title').addClass('open');
    // Accordion fuctions.
    $('.accordion').find('.accordion__title').click(function(){
        // Add class to title.
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        //Expand or collapse this panel.
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    });

});
```

The markup:

```
<div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__item">
        <h2 class="accordion__title">Question One <span class="accordion__title-icon"></span></h2>
        <div class="accordion__copy">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion__item">
        <h2 class="accordion__title">Question Two <span class="accordion__title-icon"></span></h2>
        <div class="accordion__copy">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion__item">
        <h2 class="accordion__title">Question Three <span class="accordion__title-icon"></span></h2>
        <div class="accordion__copy">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Along with a CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/aENWXz

Luckily you can see the same effect/issue using Browser Tools in Chrome using any of the mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually override the styling of hover state in touchscreen devices using a media query.

```
@media (hover: none) {
    .accordion__title {
        &:hover{
            color: #000;
        }
        &.open {
            color: #c8102e;
        }
    }
}
```